# ¿Como desplazar el scroll para que sea visible el nuevo item en una lista utilizando React JSX Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy desarrollando una chat y quiero que los mensajes nuevos se visible para eso ocupo que el scroll vertical se desplaze automáticamente cuando se agrega el nuevo mensaje

```js
  
  
   private scroll: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    //window.scrollTo(0,0);
    //ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).scrollIntoView();
    this.scroll.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth', inline: "nearest" });
  }
  
  render(){
  return(
   <div  ref={this.scroll} key={Keys}  className=" He  row">
                        <div className=" col">
                          <div className="Cuerpo">
                            <div className=" row">
                              <label className="User">{items.usuario}</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className=" Mensaje row">
                              <p className="pa">{items.mensaje}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="  row">
                              <div className="col Fecha">{items.fecha}</div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
  )
  }
```

Comment: Agrega el código que has hecho, da más detalles. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te marca error por que el compilador de typescript  detecta que la variable  puede contener null para solucionar eso tiene que usar un if por ejemplo

```
` private miScroll: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>=React.createRef();
```

componentDidUpdate() {

```
  const node=this.miScroll.current
  if(node){
     node.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth', inline: "nearest" });
    }

  }`
```

Comment: Gracias funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haga la acción de implementar un nuevo elemento agrega justo esto después que hará que baje instantáneamente hacia abajo

```
var elem=document.getElementById("myDIV");
elem.scrollTo(0,(elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight));
```

Comment: Typescript marca error (local var) elem: any
Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'elem' must be of type 'any', but here has type 'HTMLElement | null'.ts(2403)
ChatHome.tsx(100, 9): 'elem' was also declared here.